# Search a directory for a .txt file, without needing full pathname. - Java

Tags: java, file-io

I wrote a file writing script that lets you write in a file you are looking for in the console, then when you press enter it tries to find the file to see if it exists. My program works, but I don't like that I need the full pathname, every single time. I want a user to just be able to write, say, `file_name.txt` and the program searches a single directory for it.

**Currently, I must use the full pathname every single time.**  This is not all of my code, but you can see that my file names have a hard coded `String` pathname. But what if someone else wants to run the program on their own computer? I tried looking for answers to this, but Java is always very difficult for me. If you know a way to make my code generic enough so my `Scanner` object can take just the file name, that would be so helpful. Thanks, let me know if anything is unclear. I have a Mac, but it should be able to work on any OS.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileHandler {
    public static boolean fileCheck = true;
    public static File logFile;
    public static PrintWriter logPrinter;
    public static PrintWriter handMadeFile;
    public static LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    public static File fileFromScanner;
    public static File directory = new File("/Users/mizu/homework");
    public static String fileName;
    public static File file;
    public static String created = "Log has been created.";
    public static String myLogFileName = "/Users/mizu/homework/my_log.txt";
    public static String mainFileName = "/Users/mizu/homework/main_file.txt";
    public static String fileFromMethod = "/Users/mizu//homework/file_from_method.txt";
    public static String fileMessage = "I just wrote my own file contents.";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (!directory.exists())
        {
            // create new directory called homework
            directory.mkdir();
        }

        // gets file request from user
        System.out.print("Enter file to find: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = in.nextLine();

        // initialize the main_file
        fileFromScanner = new File(mainFileName);

        // if main_file exists or not, print message to my_log
        if (!fileFromScanner.exists())
        {
            // create my_log file (logFile), to keep track of events
            writeToLog(created);
            writeToLog("File path you entered: "
                    + fileName + " does not exist.");
            System.out.println(fileName + " - does not exist.");

            // create file since it doesn't exist
            File mainFile = new File(mainFileName);
            try {
                PrintWriter pwMain = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter
                        (new FileWriter(mainFile)));
                writeToLog("Created " + mainFileName);
                pwMain.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writeToLog(fileName + " already exists.");
            System.out.println(fileName + " - already exists.");
        }

        // use writeToFile method to write file, create new file name
        FileHandler testFile = new FileHandler(fileFromMethod);
        testFile.writeToFile(testFile, fileMessage);

    } // end Main
```

**All of the other methods are below here, but not shown to keep it short.**

Comment: Searching the entire computer could take a long time.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that is a good point.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel there are a ton of applets that already do this. Example: `find ` http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Comment: Depending on how you're launching the program, it might be easier to launch it from the directory the file you're looking for is in, or possibly add a file browser dialog to let the user select it graphically?

Comment: Thanks Evan, that sounds nice. I am only creating a Java application in Eclipse though, and this is an exercise I need to do for homework (unfortunately, I don't know how to do graphics). Is there a way to narrow down the search to one directory only? Like a user can type the `file_name.txt` and it will only search in one directory? It sounds so simple yet I don't know how to do it. Right now, the full path name must be typed into the console, so a full pathname search can be done. I just want to use the file name only in the console.

Comment: Thanks @Jared, except I just need it for a Java application. (I don't know much about applets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there are several tools already available to search files in a directory. However, to answer your question, I wrote a simple program that should do what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Get the absolute path from where your application has initialized
    File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    // Get user input
    String query = new Scanner(System.in).next();
    // Perform a search in the working directory
    List<File> files = search(workingDirectory, query);
    // Check if there are no matching files
    if (files.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No files found in " + workingDirectory.getPath() + " that match '"
                + query + "'");
        return;
    }
    // print all the files that matched the query
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

public static List<File> search(File file, String query) {
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    // Get all the files in this directory
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                // use recursion to search in all directories for the file
                fileList.addAll(search(f, query));
            } else if (f.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
                // if the filename matches the query, add it to the list
                fileList.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jared, that seems like it could work. I'm not very skilled in Java yet though, so I'm not sure how to implement it into my code, or even understand what is happening here. I will need to take time to study this. But I hope others find this useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! I have to read up on recursion, but this looks great.

Comment: Going to change my question to search in directory, instead of whole computer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1- You can make users set an environment variable to your path and use the path name in your code.

2- You can check the operating system, and put your files in a well-known folder. (C: for windows, /home for Ubuntu, /WhateverMacFolder for mac and if it is some other os ask user to enter the path.

3- You can create a folder in default path of your program and use it.